# debugger for django

Tags: django, debugging

how can i debug my django code ?

Comment: yes i tried that , i was actually looking for something where i can evaluate the values of different variable if and error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, I use [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) for debugging django-specific stuff.

`pdb` is useful for lower-level shell debugging, when you're using `runserver`.  Though I prefer to use ipython (`pip install ipdb`, then `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`, like you would with `pdb`)

There's also [`werkzeug`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), which, when combined with [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)' [`runserver_plus`](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/RunServerPlus) command, will allow you to open a web-based python shell on error pages:

> This item requires that you have the [Werkzeug WSGI utilities](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) (version 0.3) installed. Included with Werkzeug is a kick ass debugger that renders nice debugging tracebacks and adds an AJAX based debugger (which allows to execute code in the context of the traceback’s frames). Additionally it provides a nice access view to the source code.

Comment: django_toolbar. This is important. Gives you the ability to read session data, track back variable history - template inheritance. This is a necessity when working with django!

Comment: yes i installed werkzeug but seems like run_server plus won't work with appengine.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with the built-in Python debugger? Just insert this in your code where you want to set a breakpoint:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and execution will pause there, and the console will show a debugging prompt enabling you to inspect variables and step through the code.

Comment: and where i am supposed to see the debugging prompt on the terminal where i am running the server? and how to resume the server ?

Comment: Wooh? really? Where can I get more info on this?

Comment: See the full documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Comment: Also check out this post and vimeo tutorial on pdb: http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/31/using-pdb-python-debugger-django-debugging-series-/

Answer (score 3):

Get PyCharm from JetBrains.  It has a lovely built in debugger and Django support.

Comment: It'll pay for itself in no time.  We're talking about $100 here.

Answer (score 3):

I use Aptana Studio and pyDev - and eclipse IDE. its free and has build in django and debugging.

http://www.aptana.com/